# .NET Graph SDK - OneDrive File Upload Fails with "Unsupported segment type"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Trying to upload file using the .NET SDK for Microsoft Graph.  Here is the code:

```
 DriveItem file = new DriveItem()
        {
            File = new Microsoft.Graph.File(),
            Name = filename,
            ParentReference = new ItemReference()
            {
                DriveId = parent.ParentReference.DriveId,
                Path = path + "/" + filename
            }
        };

        var freq = _client
                .Me
                .Drive
                .Items[parent.Id]
                .Children
                .Request();

        // add the drive item
        file = await freq.AddAsync(file);

        DriveItem uploadedFile = null;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            var req = _client
                .Me
                .ItemWithPath(path + "/" + file.Name)
                .Content
                .Request();

            stream.Position = 0;
            // upload the content to the driveitem just created
            try
            {
                uploadedFile = await req.PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("File Put Error"); <<< FAILS HERE
            }
        }

        return uploadedFile;
```

An exception is thrown on the req.PutAsync method to upload the byte array containing the file contents.  I am just testing with a simple text file, less than 100 bytes in size.  The exception contains Bad Request and Unsupported segment type.

The file is created in OneDrive, but contains 0 bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me.ItemWithPath() requires the full path after /me. For example, _client.Me.ItemWithPath("/drives/driveId/items/itemId:/file/path"). This method is so the Path returned on the ItemReference returned via the API can be passed into the ItemWithPath method without any processing.

What you'll want to use is:

```
var req = _client
            .Me
            .Drive
            .ItemWithPath(path + "/" + file.Name)
            .Content
            .Request();
```

or:

```
var req = _client
            .Me
            .ItemWithPath(file.ParentReference.Path + "/" + file.Name)
            .Content
            .Request();
```

Comment: Is ItemWithPath really a property of Drive?  Or do you mean _client.Me.Drive.Items["{driveItem-Id}"].ItemWithPath(... ?

Answer (score 1):

I have found that it is sometimes easier to skip the path in lee of setting the containing folder id in the SDK statement... works in OneDrive and unified groups..

```
var createdFile = await graphClient.Me.Drive
                         .Items[currentDriveFolder.id]
                         .ItemWithPath(fileName)
                         .Content.Request()
                         .PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);
```

I would really like to be able to just set drive id and folder id like this:

```
var createdFile = await graphClient
                        .Drives[driveId]
                        .Items[folderId]
                        .ItemWithPath(fileName)
                        .Content
                        .Request()
                        .PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, and it also had the advantage of creating the file and uploading the content in a single step 