# Microsoft Graph - .NET SDK - OneDrive Large File Upload (> 4MB in size)

Tags: c#, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

Using the .NET SDK for Microsoft Graph, you can upload (small) files. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38001282/381575).

How can I upload a large file (> 4MB) using the .NET SDK?

In other words, can the SDK be utilized to implement ["Upload large files with an upload session"](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_createuploadsession) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be available in the next release of .NET Microsoft Graph client library. It will work the same as the functionality in the .NET OneDrive client library. You can review this in my working [branch](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/commit/7c037cf15413b73d1ad7b52ee027a703f4b63be1). You can provide feedback in the repo.

Comment: That's great! I'll take a look at the code. Thanks.

Comment: >I tested the code in the /MIchaelMainer/working branch, and it worked fine.

Actually, it is OK for work accounts, but it fails ("Authentication failed") for personal accounts (even small files). The documentation doesn't say anything about this being a work accounts feature only. Perhaps it is? Or is there a bug? If it is a bug, I don't see in the code where it could be, because the single difference is the account type.

(related: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/61)

Comment: Could you please tell help me with uploading a new file to onedrive? I have managed to update an existing file, but creating a new one is giving me trouble. Here is the line i used to update an existing onedrive file. 

`await client.Me.Drive.Items["55BBAC51A4E4017D!104"].Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);`

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code I wrote recently using Microsoft Graph .Net SDK.
GraphServiceClient(graphClient) authentication is required.

```
    if (fileSize.MegaBytes > 4)
                    {
                        var session = await graphClient.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(uploadPath).CreateUploadSession().Request().PostAsync();
                        var maxSizeChunk = 320 * 4 * 1024;
                        var provider = new ChunkedUploadProvider(session, graphClient, stream, maxSizeChunk);
                        var chunckRequests = provider.GetUploadChunkRequests();
                        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
                        var readBuffer = new byte[maxSizeChunk];
                        DriveItem itemResult = null;
                        //upload the chunks
                        foreach (var request in chunckRequests)
                        {
                            // Do your updates here: update progress bar, etc.
                            // ...
                            // Send chunk request
                            var result = await provider.GetChunkRequestResponseAsync(request, readBuffer, exceptions);

                            if (result.UploadSucceeded)
                            {
                                itemResult = result.ItemResponse;
                            }
                        }

                        // Check that upload succeeded
                        if (itemResult == null)
                        {
                            await UploadFilesToOneDrive(fileName, filePath, graphClient);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await graphClient.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(uploadPath).Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);
                    }
```

Comment: Could you please tell help me with uploading a new file to onedrive? I have managed to update an existing file, but creating a new one is giving me trouble. Here is the line i used to update an existing onedrive file.


`await client.Me.Drive.Items["55BBAC51A4E4017D!104"].Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);`

Comment: Do you need to close the session after the file is uploaded?

Comment: This worked great, thanks!  Have you tired it with message attachments?  I am tring and getting a Library issue

Comment: @Mike, nope, I haven't yet, It's been a while

Comment: @Azuriath please see this code https://github.com/mnakka9/OnedriveGraphUpload